# xcodebuild fails to build from terminal but succeeded from xcode

Tags: xcode, sh, ios8, xcodebuild, xcode6

I'm trying to build a framework using xcode 6-beta 3
when compiling it using xcode it works but when compiling it  from a terminal with the command:

```
xcodebuild -project <projName> -scheme <schemeName>  -configuration Debug clean build
```

I'm getting the following error

```
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.0'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
```

and the build fails to complete.
at the end of the log it says

```
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script build/myProj.build/Debug-iphoneos/myScheme.build/Script-DB9DC5BB19740464002F9181.sh
```

**upgrade:**

the script that failed is :

```
   #!/bin/sh 
# Config 
UFW_TARGET=AppCore

# Default build dir
UFW_BUILD_DIR="./build"

# Global vars
if [ -z ${SDK_NAME} ]; then

# Use the latest iphoneos SDK available
UFW_GREP_RESULT=$(xcodebuild -showsdks | grep -o "iphoneos.*$")
while read -r line; do
UFW_SDK_VERSION="${line}"
done <<< "${UFW_GREP_RESULT}"
else

# Use the SDK specified by XCode
UFW_SDK_VERSION="${SDK_NAME}"
fi

UFW_SDK_VERSION=$(echo "${UFW_SDK_VERSION}" | grep -o "[0-9].*$")

UFW_IPHONE_DIR="${UFW_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos"
UFW_SIMULATOR_DIR="${UFW_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator"
UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR="${UFW_BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal"

# Static lib name
STATIC_LIB_NAME="appCore"
UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR="${STATIC_LIB_NAME}.framework"

# Build Framework

rm -rf ${UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR}

xcodebuild ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" -target "${UFW_TARGET}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos${UFW_SDK_VERSION} clean build RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO

if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then echo >&2 "Error: xcodebuild failed"; exit 1; fi

xcodebuild ARCHS="i386 x86_64" -target "${UFW_TARGET}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator${UFW_SDK_VERSION} clean build RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO

if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then echo >&2 "Error: xcodebuild failed"; exit 1; fi

mkdir -p "${UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers"

cp -a "${UFW_IPHONE_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}/Headers" "${UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}"

echo "running lipo -create -ouput..."
lipo -create -output "${UFW_UNIVERSAL_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}/${STATIC_LIB_NAME}" "${UFW_IPHONE_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}/${STATIC_LIB_NAME}" "${UFW_SIMULATOR_DIR}/${UFW_FRAMEWORK_DIR}/${STATIC_LIB_NAME}"
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then echo >&2 "Error: lipo failed for ${STATIC_LIB_NAME}"; exit 1; fi
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong ? 
 any help be much appreciated

Comment: What is the content of the script that fails?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found an answer.
Since custom frameworks were announced only in iOS 8, `-sdk iphonesimulator8.0`  need to be added to the script, it defines Xcode to build the project only for Ios 8.
it should look like:

```
xcodebuild -project <projName> -scheme <schemeName> -sdk iphonesimulator8.0 -configuration Debug clean build
```

this code works

Comment: Any ideas how this can be set when `xcodebuild` ran by `Carthage`?