# Carthage fails to start when running from Xcode 10 Build pre-action

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I have simple ksh script which runs 
`carthage update --platform iOS` as a Build pre-action and it started to fail after updating to Xcode 10.
Running the command in Terminal generates `Carthage` folder successfully.

To reproduce this issue, quit Xcode and delete `DerivedData` and `Carthage` folder. Then open Xcode 10 and try to build.

The error I get:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios8.0-simulator'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal armv7
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(4 failures)
Build Failed
```

#### Setup

- Carthage 0.31.1 - 0.33.0
- `Cartfile` points to Alamofire 4.7.3

#### Things I have tried

- Using `carthage bootstrap`, didn't work
- Raising Alamofire dependency target to iOS 8.4 and 10 (from local fork), didn't work
- All answers from [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558933/error-unable-to-load-standard-library-for-target-arm64-apple-ios10-0-simulator), didn't work
- Use `env -i` as advised in [open Carthage ticket](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2613), didn't work

#### Solutions

- Select "Generic iOS Device" when building first time.
- Passing SDK parameter directly to `xcodebuild`, [found in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881932/1162044.) This forces you to write your own `carthage update`, composed of checkout and build. Only this option worked as Xcode Build pre-action step. [The solution was tested.](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2613#issuecomment-432993359)

#### Some links

[Non answered thread on Apples forums.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/331126)

[Closed Alamofire ticket](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2612)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **solution** that **worked** for me was to unset one of the env variables coming from XCode 10 just before executing carthage update:

unset LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_SUFFIX

carthage update

Comment: worked like a charm ... could you point to any documentation that talks about this env var?

Comment: This worked for me in Xcode 10.1 and arthage 0.31.2

Comment: Anyone else able to get this to work on Xcode 10.3? It's not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, restarting macOS fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that actually does the trick and its:

> write one valid command write after carthage update command

So follow this checklist:

- Ensure that your command line tools are configured to use Xcode 10.1. Run the following command from Terminal:

  `sudo xcode-select -s <path to Xcode 10.1>/Contents/Developer`
- Ensure that script file has required permissions:

  `chmod 777 <path-to-script-file>`
- Write one valid command write after `carthage update` command, For example `echo succeed` (This actually do the trick):

  [image: Example]

**Tested environment:**

- `Carthage 0.31.2`
- `Xcode 10.1`

**Working Demo**

https://github.com/MojtabaHs/Carthage-WorkingDemo

### - THE MOST IMPORTANT STEP

- **DON'T FORGET** to write one valid command write after carthage update command

Note that this is just a hack around the issue explained in question, not all carthage issues.

Comment: That's a negative. The particular issue only occurs when running Carthage as a Run Script Build Phase defined in Xcode. I get the same behavior in 0.31.2 and 10.1 as I have observed with 0.31.1 and 10.0. Carthage works fine on the command line directly.

Do you have this working in a sample project?

Comment: I also experience the same issue with Carthage 0.31.2 and Xcode 10.1.

Comment: @DávidPásztor try following step by step guid that I added.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini still no luck. I have a way more complex pre-build script than simply calling `carthage update`, so it already  executes quite a few valid commands after `carthage update`. I'm calling a shell script from the pre-build action, not writing `carthage update` directly into the pre-build action.

Comment: Checkout the demo. It uses script file as the original question needs. @DávidPásztor

Comment: I don't have your complicated script to test, but I think you can add the echo after calling your script like: `"${SRCROOT}/UpdateCarthage.ksh"
echo succeed` @DávidPásztor

Comment: Indeed, if you check out your very own example @MojtabaHosseini, delete the `Carthage` folder, and re-run Xcode, the build will fail because the actual carthage update step fails to build the Alamofire framework.

Comment: Anyway, FWIW, I'm working around this by just alerting developers to run our "carthage update/bootstrap" script when we detect a change in the Cartfile and/or the Cartfile.resolved. And, CI is doing the same but with a shell step of its own that executes the carthage update script as necessary before running xcodebuild.

Comment: This does not work for me either, as @bensnider has described

Comment: `No entry found for dependencies echo, succeed in Cartfile.`